# Closure en javascript

Tags: javascript, funcion

este ejercicio es de una biblioteca que tiene libros y empleados y tiene los metodos de anadir libro, obtener el libro que se anadio, vender libro y obtener el nombre del libro que se vendio y prestamo de un libro

```
const biblioteca = (function(){
    let _libro;
    let _empleado;
    let libros=['El Principito', 'La Sirenita', 'Blanca Nieves', 'El Rey Leon', 'Caperucita']

    
    function addLibro(libro){
       _libro = libro
       libros.push(_libro)
    }
    function getLibro() {
        indiceaddLibro = libros.length-1
        return 'el libro anadido se llama: ', libros[indiceaddLibro]
    }
    function sellBook(libro){
        let indiceLibro = libros.indexOf(libro)
        let libroVendido = libros.splice(indiceLibro,1)
    }
    function getSellBook(){
        return libroVendido

    }
    function prestamoLibro(libro){
        return 'El libro tiene un prestamo de 5 dias habiles,debe regresarse en el estado en el que se entrego y si hay demora hay que pagar 10% del costo del libro'
    }
return {
    addLibro, 
    getLibro,
    sellBook,
    getSellBook, 
    prestamoLibro
}})();

biblioteca.addLibro('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getLibro())
biblioteca.sellBook('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getSellBook())
```

sin embargo cuando ejecuto el codigo me dice que libroVendido no esta definido en la linea donde dice function getSellBook(), que podra ser? soy principiante en esto por favor agradeceria ayuda

Comment: Primero, esto no tiene nada que ver con la closure, si no con el `scope`. Una variable definida dentro de una función solo va a estar definida dentro de dicha función. Y esto no es javascript, es programación básica, casi todos los lenguajes hacen lo mismo. Hay cosas que modifican eso, pero por regla general, es así. Te dice que no está definido porque ... bueno, no existe en esa función! Ni en el objeto, así que no puede verlo. Declara libroVendido en tu objeto (al lado de `_libro`) y en la función `sellBook` lo asignas, de esa manera siempre podrás verla

Answer (score 0):

Para que la funcion **getSellBook** pueda acceder a la variable libroVendido, la variable debe estar en un scope superior, por eso despues de `let libros=[...]` le agregue `let libroVendido = null`.

Como declaramos la variable **libroVendido** en el scope superior para que no haya conflictos por redeclararla, dentro de la funcion sellBook quitamos el let quedando `libroVendido = libros.splice(indiceLibro,1)`, de esta forma ya no esta redeclarado y por el scope sabe que se refiere a la variable superior.

```
const biblioteca = (function(){
    let _libro;
    let _empleado;
    let libros=['El Principito', 'La Sirenita', 'Blanca Nieves', 'El Rey Leon', 'Caperucita']

    let libroVendido = null

    ....
    ....
    ....
    
    function sellBook(libro){
        let indiceLibro = libros.indexOf(libro)
        libroVendido = libros.splice(indiceLibro,1)
    }
    
    
}})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Aca te dejo un ejemplo de lo mismo que hiciste, convertido en clases y metodos, compara las similiditudes y diferencias, si tenes alguna duda sobre el codigo dejame un comentario.

salduos.

Le agregue un poco de manejo de dom, para insertar las listas.

```js
class Biblioteca{
   constructor(){
      this.libroVendido = ""
      
      this.libros = 
       [
         'El Principito', 
         'La Sirenita', 
         'Blanca Nieves', 
         'El Rey Leon', 
         'Caperucita'
       ]
      
    }
    
    addLibro = (libro) => this.libros.push(libro)
    
    geAddLibro = () => `Ultimo libro agregado: ${this.libros[this.libros.length-1]}`

    sellBook = (libro) => this.libros = this.libros.filter(item => item != this.setVendido(libro) )
     
    setVendido = (libro) => this.libroVendido = libro && libro

    getSellBook = () => `Ultimo libro vendido: ${this.libroVendido}`

    prestamoLibro = (libro) => `
        El libro tiene un prestamo de 5 dias habiles,
        debe regresarse en el estado en el que se entrego 
        y si hay demora hay que pagar 10% del costo del libro
     `
     
   showAllBooks = (div, mm) => document.getElementById(div).innerHTML += `${mm}<br/>${this.libros.map(item  => item).join("<br/>")}<br/><br/>`

}

let biblioteca = new Biblioteca();

biblioteca.showAllBooks("libros", "Lista Original:")

biblioteca.addLibro('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.geAddLibro())
biblioteca.showAllBooks("libros", "Se Agrego:")

biblioteca.sellBook('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getSellBook())
biblioteca.showAllBooks("libros", "Se quito:")
```

```html
<div id="libros"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> La instrucción let declara una variable de alcance local con ámbito de
> bloque(block scope) en tu caso solo el ámbito dentro de
> sellBook(libro){ .... } para poder obtener el resultado que buscas
> modificando el codigo nos queda que:

```js
const biblioteca = (function(){
    let _libro;
    let LibroVendido
    let _empleado;
    let libros=['El Principito', 'La Sirenita', 'Blanca Nieves', 'El Rey Leon', 'Caperucita']

    
    function addLibro(libro){
       _libro = libro
       libros.push(_libro)
    }
    function getLibro() {
        indiceaddLibro = libros.length-1
        return 'el libro anadido se llama: ', libros[indiceaddLibro]
    }
    function sellBook(libro){
       // console.log(libros)
        let Libro = libros.filter(e=>e==libro)
        console.log(Libro);
       libroVendido=libro.toString();
       
    }
    function getSellBook(){
        return libroVendido

    }
    function prestamoLibro(libro){
        return 'El libro tiene un prestamo de 5 dias habiles,debe regresarse en el estado en el que se entrego y si hay demora hay que pagar 10% del costo del libro'
    }
return {
    addLibro, 
    getLibro,
    sellBook,
    getSellBook, 
    prestamoLibro
}})();

biblioteca.addLibro('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getLibro())
biblioteca.sellBook('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getSellBook())
```

Answer (score 0):

Es verdad que se esta formando un **scope closure** dentro de la función `biblioteca`, pero el problema que se describe, esta mas relacionado al uso del `scope`.

> sin embargo cuando ejecuto el codigo me dice que libroVendido no esta definido en la linea donde dice function getSellBook()

---

#### Scope JS: generalidades

Al iniciar un programa JS se van creando **contextos de ejecución**.

Estos contextos existen en espacios de memoria llamados `scope`,
en este `scope` hay variables y expresiones que se pueden **ver/usar/referenciar**:

```
//global scope curly brace implicito
const biblioteca = (function(){
    //codigo
})();
//JS: biblioteca esta en este scope global, la puedo referenciar
biblioteca.addLibro('Cenicienta’);
console.log(biblioteca.getLibro())
biblioteca.sellBook('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getSellBook())
```

Además, estos `scopes` pueden formar capas anidadas por cada función, en donde las capas hijo pueden **ver/usar/referenciar** al `scope` de las capas padre:

```
const biblioteca = (function(){
    //Capa 1: Parent local scope biblioteca
    let _libro;
    let libros=['El Principito', 'La Sirenita', 'Blanca Nieves', 'El Rey Leon', 'Caperucita']

    
    function addLibro(libro){
        //Capa 2: Child local scope addLibro
        //JS: puedo acceder a la variable _libro, esta en el scope de la capa Padre
       _libro = libro
       libros.push(_libro)
    }
    
    function getLibro() {
        //Capa 2: Child local scope getLibro
        //JS: puedo acceder a la variable libros, esta en el scope de la capa Padre
        let indiceaddLibro = libros.length-1;
                return 'el libro anadido se llama: ', libros[indiceaddLibro]
    }
    
    function sellBook(libro){
        //Capa 2: Child local scope sellBook
        //JS: indiceLibro/libroVendido  solo estan declaradas en este scope
        //JS: puedo acceder a la variable libros, esta en el scope de la capa Padre
        let indiceLibro = libros.indexOf(libro)
        let libroVendido = libros.splice(indiceLibro,1)
    }
    
return {
    addLibro,
    getLibro,
    //code…
}})();

biblioteca.addLibro('Cenicienta')
console.log(biblioteca.getLibro()); // Cenicienta
biblioteca.sellBook('Cenicienta’);
```

Ahora bien, si una variable no se encuentra en el `scope`, no se puede **ver/usar/referenciar**:

```
const biblioteca = (function(){
    let _libro;
    let libros=['El Principito', 'La Sirenita', 'Blanca Nieves', 'El Rey Leon', 'Caperucita']

    
    function addLibro(libro){
       //codigo…
    }
    
    function getLibro() {
       //codigo…
    }
    
    function sellBook(libro){
       //codigo…
    }
    
    function getSellBook(){
        //Capa 2: Child local scope getSellBook
      //JS: la variable libroVendido no se puede ver/usar
        //no esta declarada en este scope, ni en el parent scope
        return libroVendido
    }

    return {
        //codigo…
}})();

//…codigo
console.log(biblioteca.getSellBook()) //JS: libroVendido is not defined
```

La pieza de código del OP, mostrará el siguiente mensaje en consola:

> ReferenceError: libroVendido is not defined

---

#### Uso de variables entre Parent Scope y Child scope

Luego, para poder **ver/usar/referenciar** la variable `libroVendido`, desde el `Child local scope getSellBook`, se debe declarar o en el mismo `Child local scope`, o para este caso de uso en el `Parent local scope biblioteca`:

```
const biblioteca = (function(){
    //Capa 1: Parent local scope biblioteca
    let _libro;
    let _empleado;
    let libros=['El Principito', 'La Sirenita', 'Blanca Nieves', 'El Rey Leon', 'Caperucita']
    //Declaración de variable en el Parent scope biblioteca
    let libroVendido = []

    ....
    ....
    ....
    function sellBook(libro){
        //Capa 2: Child local scope sellBook
        //JS: indiceLibro solo esta declarada en este scope
        let indiceLibro = libros.indexOf(libro)
        //JS: libroVendido se puede ver/usar, esta en el scope de la capa Padre
        libroVendido = libros.splice(indiceLibro,1)
     }

    
     function getSellBook(){
        //Capa 2: Child local scope getSellBook
      //JS: libroVendido se puede ver/usar, esta en el scope de la capa Padre
        return libroVendido
    
    
}})();
```

Nótese lo siguiente:

- Se movió la declaración de la variable `libroVendido` desde `Child local scope sellBook` al `Parent local scope biblioteca`.
- Esto permitira que el `Child local scope sellBook/getSellBook`  pueda **ver/usar/referenciar**  la variable `libroVendido`, la cual se encuentra en el `Parent local scope biblioteca`.

Finalmente, al **acceder/ver/usar** a una variable desde un `Child scope`, cuya declaración se encuentra en un `Parent Scope` se forma un `closure scope`.

#### Notas de campo

- Cada `scope` esta encerrado entre curly braces `{scope}`, el global scope no tiene, son implícitas.
- Se puede crear una imágen mental en las capas anidadas, [observando el código y los curly braces](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Code-example-containing-three-nested-scopes-Sim14_fig1_316208960)

Enlaces:

[Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.